# Displaying Date Overlaps from a single Table in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, date, duplicates, range, overlap

I have the following **Episode** table example:

Please note, where DischDate= "2020-02-20" means - client hasn't been discharged.
It's like NULL (this date meant to fill out NULL)

[image]

My goal is do display all possible overlaps within the same EHRClientFK, as following:

See the schema of my all possible Overlaps:
[image]

So, in this table's case I expect to display -
EHRClientFK / AdmDate / DischDate for only EHRClientFK = 2, 4, 3, 5 (which satisfies the schema):

This should be the resulting table:
[image]

EHRClientFK values 8,9,10 have no duplicate (overlaps), Clients 6, 7 have two adm-disch dates, but they
are NOT overlapping betw. each other

To achieve this result, I have the following code:

```
     SELECT 
           a.[EHRClientFK]
          ,a.[AdmDate]
          ,a.[DischDate]

    FROM [WH].[dbo].[Episode] a
    INNER JOIN [WH].[dbo].[Episode] b ON a.EHRClientFK = b.EHRClientFK 

    WHERE
         ((a.DischDate = '2020-02-20') AND (b.DischDate = '2020-02-20'))
      OR ((a.AdmDate < b.DischDate) AND (b.AdmDate < a.DischDate))


   GROUP BY
           a.[EHRClientFK]
          ,a.[AdmDate]
          ,a.[DischDate]

   HAVING COUNT (*) >1
```

But, when I apply this on my original Table (with over 20K records) - I am still having non duplicate
EHRClientFK, like 8,9,10 (very insignificant amount, but still); and some cases of 6,7 with NO overlapping dates

How should I change my **Where** clause in order to satisfy my Overlap schema (to cover all overlap cases)"?

Comment: The second half of your expression checks for overlaps, although the usual operator is `<=`, rather than `<`, so that episodes having one date in common are considered overlapping. The first half of your expression requires that _both_ episodes have not ended in discharge. It also fails to take into account the possibility of an overlap between one episode ending in discharge and another episode that doesn't. Had you used `NULL` rather than a _magic date_ you could have used `where a.AdmDate <= Coalesce( b.DischDate, a.AdmDate ) and b.AdmDate <= Coalesce( a.DischDate, b.AdmDate )`.

Comment: @HABO Yes, I'll update the 2nd half of the expression
But that's not my main concern - the main problem is that I am still getting the clients that were attended only once (EHRClientFK = 8,9,10 cases), even after I stated "HAVING COUNT (*) >1" in my code! Why?   
Also, and this is the most significant problem - I am getting some values that are NON Overlaps...
I'll rephrase my main question - "How should I change my Where clause in order to satisfy my Overlap schema (to cover all overlap cases)"?

About NULL - The original table in my DB has '2050-12-01' date instead of NULL

Comment: Another popular term to add to the condition is something like `where a.EHRClientFK < b.EHRClientFK and ( ... )`. That ensures that: (1) you don't compare every row to itself and (ii) that you don't compare rows to each other twice, e.g. comparing "bar" and "foo", then "foo" and "bar".